# PhantomJS fails with no error

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs

I am running phantomJS 2.1.0, and I am using it to generate pdfs of a page on my angularJS site. On my development server with un-minified code everything works perfectly. On my production server with minified code I get an error about my module not being loaded. When I use minified code on my development server I get no error and no messages at all, phantomJS just reports that it loaded the page fine but none of the javascript on the page runs. I can also see that phantomJS retrieves all the proper resources for the page.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else ever runs into this very frustrating issue, I eventually found that the bug was with my highcharts code. When defining the configuration of one of my charts I had defined the same property twice. E.g. (I defined legend twice):

```
$('#data-chart').highcharts({
                title: {
                    style: {
                        display: 'none'
                    }
                },
                credits: false, //do not show 'Highcharts.com' on chart
                colors: ['#264653', '#2a9d8f', '#e9c46a', '#f4a261', '#e76f51', '#67a9e5', '#f8ed08', '#7b69a9','#91e8e1'],
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                yAxis: [
                    {title: { text: null } },
                    {
                        opposite: true,         //show secondary y-axis on right side of graph
                        title: { text: null }   //Hide y-axis title
                    }
                ],
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        pointPadding: 0,
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        groupPadding: 0.15
                    },
                    series: {
                        stacking: 'normal'
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    shared: true
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    symbolWidth: 16,
                    symbolPadding: 10,
                    itemStyle: {
                        color: '#a8aab7',
                        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        fontSize: '14px'
                    }

                }
            });
```

Removing the second definition fixed everything. I suspect the problem is that the browser can handle double properties by ignoring one but phantomJS can't so it fails silently. I'm still unsure why minifying the code broke it but it worked un-minified, since all my controllers are imported regardless of the page you are on but maybe it is an angularJS optimization that it only parses the code for the controllers currently being used, but when minified it parses everything. Or during minification it did something to the double properties that broke phantomJS's parsing of that code.

Comment: Adding to this, it is good practice to run your code through node or similar, if you have a problem with phantom, since there are a lot of cases in which phantom breaks without message.

Comment: @MaxUppenkamp Could you expand on your comment? I don't understand what you mean by running the code through node or similar. Just run 'node <minified javascript file>'?